# How to change DataGridView column type after binding

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewcombobox

I have loaded a DataGridView called `dgvPrint` with a List which retrieve from database as follows:

```
dgvPrint.DataSource = ReservedServices.GetAll();
```

The result is like as below:

[image: initial data]

`Worker` column and `ServiceType` column are some integers which refer to primary keys of two tables.

How can I change the column type of `ServiceType` and `Worker` from simple text to `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` ?

**Note1:** The current values of these two columns are the `ValueMember` of corresponding ComboBoxes.

**Note2:** I want to preserve other columns' data and positions.

I have used this code for `Worker` column, but it does not work properly:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn colbox;
colbox = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dgvPrintServices.Columns[4];
colbox.DataSource = WorkerServices.GetAll(); // a list of worker with Id and Name
colbox.DisplayMember = "Name";
colbox.ValueMember = "Id";
dgvPrint.Columns.Add(colbox);
```

Comment: So you also want to see the Combobox in read-mode?

Comment: Actually NO, especially I want to change the worker

Comment: So, you are currently getting a TextBox when you edit the worker column?

Comment: @RandRandom , I have set readonly = false in datagridview, however I could not edit the text

Answer (score 0):

You have to **first** define and add columns to the DataGridView (either using GUI in VS or by code as per example bellow), setting a correct .DataPropertyName. One of those columns will be Worker column, which will also have extra code, the code you listed in your post. And **then** add the datasource.

In another words, I think your code is correct, but order of assigning datasource and setting columns properties has to change.

VB.NET:

```
    With WIcol4
        .Width = "120"
        .HeaderText = "Worker"
        .DataPropertyName = "Worker"
        .DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
        .DefaultCellStyle.Padding = New Padding(0, 0, 6, 0)
        .DropDownWidth = 300
        .Name = .DataPropertyName
        .DataSource = dtWorker
        .ValueMember = "ID"
        .DisplayMember = "Name"
        .ReadOnly = False
    End With

    Me.dgwOps.Columns.Add(WIcol4)
```

C#:

```
    var _with1 = WIcol4;
   _with1.Width = "120";
   _with1.HeaderText = "Worker";
   _with1.DataPropertyName = "Worker";
   _with1.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
   _with1.DefaultCellStyle.Padding = New Padding(0, 0, 6, 0);
   _with1.DropDownWidth = 300;
   _with1.Name = _with1.DataPropertyName;
   _with1.DataSource = dtWorker;
   _with1.ValueMember = "ID";
   _with1.DisplayMember = "Name";
   _with1.ReadOnly = False;

   this.dgwOps.Columns.Add(WIcol4);
```

Note, that for a column to be writable, **both** DataGridView and the column has to be ReadOnly = False.